# what are the top js lib/framework/tool i should know?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

i know the basics of js the language for several years, but never had a need to go deeper than say change a style of a paragraph or do a image rollover or validate a field.

am thinking going deeper with js.

can anyone recommend the top 3 library or framework that you cant live without?

Xah

Comment: Personally I find http://erkie.github.com/ invaluable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What JavaScript library would you choose for a new project and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913/what-javascript-library-would-you-choose-for-a-new-project-and-why)

Comment: Should be community wiki; also has probably been asked before.

Comment: thanks. all great answers. Very nice link Nikita. I would have marked that the Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's ask [Stack Overflow Tag Trends](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tagtrend.html):

[image]

Comment: So prototype and mootools are much easier to use than jquery? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Its really a personal choice, but:

- [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (Serverside JS)
- [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) or [Capuccino](http://cappuccino.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jsframeworks/?ca=dgr-dwexnbarbw